# Can't install Python Packages with PyCharm ("Non-zero exit code (1)")

Tags: windows-10, python

New to coding. Using PyCharm 19.2, and Python 3.7 (32-bit). When i try to install any package I get this error. I currently have pip 19.0.3. When I try to upgrade to 19.2.3, it says I have installed it successfully but it does not display the newer version of pip under the package list.

PyCharm suggests running the command "pip install numpy" in the terminal. When attempted, this results in the error "There was a problem confirming the ssl certifi
cate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip
/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)')))"

What else can I try?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem on Windows 10 with PyCharm. Found my antivirus (Eset "Smart Security") was configured to filter SSL/TLS I disabled it in Eset and problem was solved.